# Paste the string to a text box. Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a chrome extension that requires copy and pasting text. Suppose a user selects some text on any webpage, it should be copied into a variable and when the user presses ctrl+3, (if in a textbox or somewhere where our normal ctrl+v works) it should paste it. A normal copy paste tool but with different shortcuts.

Currently my script has this function:
I am retrieving the data correctly but don't know how to paste it.

```
var copy_paste1;
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 49 && evt.ctrlKey) {
        var c = window.getSelection();
        copy_paste1 = c
        alert(copy_paste1);
        document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 51 && evt.ctrlKey) {
        alert(copy_paste1);
        //****INSTEAD OF THIS ALERT I WANT TO PASTE!
    }
};
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) to get the currently focused element, and then try to set it's value:

```
document.activeElement.value = copy_paste1;
```

This is, of course, the bare bones approach - it would be recommended to at least add some checks before  simply trying to set the value (ie. check if type is textbox, textarea, etc.), but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach. 
But I don't know why it doesn't seem to work. I tried it on a stackoverflow page. When I press Ctrl+1, it readily copies it and alerts. But when I am trying to paste it by Ctrl+3 nothing is getting pasted.

Comment: Possibly because Ctrl+<Number> is reserved for tab switching in Chrome. I doubt you can use it, because there is strictly no way to override it.

Comment: I checked. It isn't the case atleast in my version of browser. 
Both the alerts were working fine earlier. 
Somehow, document.activeElement.value = copy_paste1 doesn't seem to work. I mean the operation is going because i tried to put a test alert afterwards but nothing is getting pasted.

Comment: I figured out the problem but am unable to solve it. 
The variable copy_paste1 doesn't have anything under it even after copying.

Comment: if (evt.keyCode == 51 && evt.ctrlKey) {
    curElement=document.activeElement;
    alert(copy_paste1);
    curElement.value=copy_paste1;
    alert("Done");
}
But when I do this in a text area. I get a blank alert, nothing is copied to the text area and then an alert saying Done. 
If I do curElement.value=copy_paste1 to curElement.value="Hi", the text area gets changed. Why am I not able to retrieve the variable when the activeElement is something of a text area or an input box?