# Paste a variable in document.activeElement.value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that needs to paste the contents of a variable into a text area/box.

```
//copy_paste1 is a variable which has a string stored in it at this point. 
// Exact value is Hi'
if (evt.keyCode == 51 && evt.ctrlKey) {
    curElement=document.activeElement;
    alert(copy_paste1);
    curElement.value=copy_paste1;
    alert("Done");
}
```

This is the code for the execution. When I try and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (keyCode Ctrl+51) on a random element like text say. I get an alert saying `Hi`. And then an alert saying `Done`.

But when I do this in a text area. I get a blank alert, nothing is copied to the text area and then an alert saying `Done`.

When I change `curElement.value=copy_paste1` to `curElement.value="Hi"`, the text area gets changed. Why am I not able to retrieve the variable when the active Element is something of a text area or an input box?

Comment: Of note: previous question by this user, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895921/paste-the-string-to-a-text-box-chrome-extension

Comment: For textarea, may using "innerHTML" instead of value, for input you did change the value property, but remember, textarea is lie <textarea> value </textarea>

Comment: Even for input, I cannot access the variable. I can only access the variable when I press ctrl+3 on static text.

Comment: Have you tried other key combinations, just to exclude effect of pre-assigned shortcuts?

Comment: @Teraglehn I don't believe you.

Comment: everything's fine. http://jsfiddle.net/RLuP3/

Comment: Maybe i wrong, maybe i'm right, just try xD

Comment: Xan - Yes I have tried other key combinations which are unused by chrome.
@guest-This seems fine, the one on fiddle. However when I run the same script as an extension and do it on the stackoverflow search bar. It doesn't work!!

Comment: Also, 
Like I said: 
If I do curElement.value="Hi". It works almost everywhere. In inputs, textboxes and areas.
But if I do curElement.value=some_variable. IT JUST DOESN'T WORK IN INPUTS, TEXT AREAS. It works on normal blank html and text.

Comment: The variable comes as undefined. :/